# Best way (other than session) to store objects in Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, controller

I have a rails controller

```
class Controllername < application
  def method1
    obj = API_CALL
    session =obj.access_token 
     redirect_to redirect_url    #calls the API authorization end point 
                            #and redirects to action method2  
  end
  def method2    
    obj.call_after_sometime
  end
end
```

I am calling some API's in method1 getting a object and storing access token and secrets in a session. `method1` finishes it's action.

After sometime I am calling `method2`, now the session(access token, secrets) is stored correctly.

But, now inside `method2` I need to call the API `call_after_sometime` using the OBJECT `obj`.But, now `obj` is unavailable because I didn't store it in a session(We will get a SSL error storing encrypted objects).

I want to know what's the best way to store `obj` in `method1` so that it can be used later in `method2`

EDIT:

when I tried Rails.cache or Session I am getting the error

```
 TypeError - no _dump_data is defined for class OpenSSL::X509::Certificate
```

Googling it I found when I store encrypted values in session it will throw this error.

Comment: use instance variable `@obj`

Comment: I tried it. It's becoming nil in `method2`

Comment: If controller class is remains loaded during both the call then why not you try `class variable`.

Comment: I am not that familiar with the usage of class variable. To what value should I initialize.

Comment: You should never set `session = <something>`.  treat session like a hash into which you can store values, so you would say `session[:foo] = "bar"` for example.

Comment: Max williams I am treating session as a hash only. The above code is just a sample. I am storing session[:obj] and its throwing SSL error

Comment: @Rocky29 do you access method1 and method2 in the same request, or do you need to object in subsequent requests?

Comment: @Mohammed it's on subsequent request not the same request

Comment: @Rocky29 did you find any solution for this.

Answer (score 6):

You can try caching it, but be careful of the caching key, if the object is unique per user then add the user id in the caching key

```
class Controllername < application
  def method1
    obj = API_CALL
    Rails.cache.write("some_api_namespace/#{current_user.id}", obj)
    session =obj.access_token 
  end
  def method2
    obj = Rails.cache.read("some_api_namespace/#{current_user.id}")
    obj.call_after_sometime
  end
end
```

If there's a possibility that the cache might not be existent when you try to read it, then you could use `fetch` instead of `read` which will call the api if it doesn't find the data

```
def method2
  obj = Rails.cache.fetch("some_api_namespace/#{current_user.id}") do
    method_1
  end
  obj.call_after_sometime
end
```

[more info here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching) and I also [wrote about it here](http://blog.abushady.com/2015/04/02/using_rails_low_level_caching.html)

Comment: sry for the delay. But, when I tried it . It's getting the same error as using the session (SSL error)

Comment: could you add that error to the question, also `obj.class` to know the class of that object

Comment: @Rocky29 what api are you using ?

Comment: I am using a third party API where during redirection from method1 it sends some authorization values to method2 and with the obj.call_after-sometime and the authorization value I need to make future API calls. My problem is obj becomes nil once it reaches method2

Comment: the object probably can't be serialized for some reason, you should find the minimum amount of data that you can save that allows you to do the subsequent requests, instead of saving the object as a whole, like for example would this access token be enough ?

Comment: No, I need the whole object. I am able to store the access token in the session. But, I need the whole object for further processing

Comment: I can't really help you at this point, I don't know enough to suggest more answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: write obj into a key in the session and read it out again in the second method.

```
class Controllername < application
  def method1
    obj = API_CALL
    session[:obj] = obj
  end
  def method2    
    if obj = session[:obj]
      obj.call_after_sometime
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: this is not working since the obj contains encrypted objects it's throwing SSL error

Comment: Just write the access token instead then, or whatever you need to do "call_after_sometime"

Comment: I need the whole object not only the access token. on subsequent calls value of variable obj( instance or class) becoming null on method2 where i need it to be the same as in method2. do you have any solutions?