# Instance variable getting reset after subsequent calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to ROR.

I have a controller

```
class Controllername < application
  def method1
    @obj = API_CALL
    redirect_to redirect_url    #calls the API authorization end point 
                                #and redirects to action method2 
  end

  def method2    #redirection to this action
     @obj.somemethod  #this value is null
  end
end
```

My problem is when I use Instance variable or class varaible @obj or @@obj becomes nil in the action method2. I want this value to be whatever the value in method1.

Note: SESSION note helping as it's giving SSL error.

Any help is kindly appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is how it's designed, instance variables aren't carried along to subsequent requests

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way (other than session) to store objects in Rails controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30119531/best-way-other-than-session-to-store-objects-in-rails-controller)

Comment: you have to recreate object variable or class variable on second method, with pass some ids to second method, I think there are no way without session

Answer (score 0):

Of cause using an instance variable doesn't work because the instance of the class only exists inside the `method1` or `method2` method .

What you can do is using class variables. You can set them using `class_variable_set(:@@class_variable_name, value)` and get them using `class_variable_get(::@@class_variable_name)` again. In your case it whould look like this:

```
class Controllername < application
  def method1
    class_variable_set(:@@api_call_data, API_CALL)
    redirect_to redirect_url    #calls the API authorization end point 
                                #and redirects to action method2 
  end

  def method2    #redirection to this action
     class_variable_get(:@@api_call_data).somemethod  #this value is null
  end
end
```

Of cause this only works if the data is the same to every user if the data is user specific you need to use a class variable name that is user specific.